# Getting comment box to appear and disappear

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

```
<html>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js">    
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addcomment").click(function () {
        $("#postComment").show();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<style>
    #postComment { display: none; }
</style>

        <cfform name="InsertComments" id="InsertComments">
            <fieldset>
<div id="container">
    <div id="mainContent">
    <div><a href="#" id="addcomment">add comment</a></div>
        <div id='postComment'>
            <cftextarea name="Remarks" cols="55" rows="4" label="Tour Description"
                                    required="yes" validateat="OnSubmit" message="Please enter your comment here" 
                                    enabled="no">
                        </cftextarea>
            <cfinput type="text" name="Image_ID" message="Please enter Account Here." 
                                 validateat="onSubmit" required="yes" id="Image_ID" size="10"
                                 maxlength="60">
                        </cfinput>
        <cfinput type="submit" name="insertComments" value="Insert Comments" id="submit">
                        </cfinput>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </fieldset>
    </cfform>
        <cfif IsDefined("form.InsertComments")>

                    <cfquery datasource="AccessTest">
                        INSERT INTO CommentsDB (Remarks, Image_ID, Date_Time )
                        VALUES
                        (<cfqueryparam value="#form.Remarks#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR">
                    </cfqueryparam>
                        , <cfqueryparam value="#form.Image_ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
                    </cfqueryparam>
                        , <cfqueryparam value="#now()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
                    </cfqueryparam>
                        )
                    </cfquery>

            </cfif>

</div>

</html>
```

What more would I need to get this to work?

[image]

Comment: As I have said in a previous post of yours.  You are making your life harder by using cfform, cfinput, cftextarea. These offer you nothing but headaches. They are also loading a boat load of JS that you aren't even using. Just use standard form controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return false;` to the end of the click handler.

Change js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addcomment").click(function () {
        $("#postComment").show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Add CSS:

```
<style>
    #postComment { display: none; }
</style>
```

Change HTML like this:

```
<div><a href="#" id="addcomment">add comment</a></div>
```

Comment: I am having some trouble with the CSS part. Is there anything I should wrap it in?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes you need to wrap all css in `<style></style>` brackets unless it is in a separate file (which it should be). See edit above.

Comment: This hides it, but now I can't get it to unhide.

Comment: Nothing happens when you click the link? To debug use the developer tools console. I would first make sure the $.ready function is executing (use a `console.log()`), then make sure the click event handler is executing on click (use another `console.log`), and lastly make sure the $ selectors are working (you can just query them in the console). Also keep an eye on the `#postComment` node in the DOM to watch for style changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toggle()` instead of `show()`.

```
$("#addcomment").click(function () {
   $("#postComment").toggle("slow");
});
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n9ucR/2/)***

Comment: Does not seem to be doing anything.

Comment: @MichaelDowney - there are also syntax errors. see in your console for `Uncaught syntax error`. Use brackets as above..